# Do the pokemons appear stronger by the time of the day?

Tags: pokemon-go

I find the pokemons I encounter in the mornings appear to be much stronger in the mornings rather than at night, is it true?

**Insights:**

- Level: 16
- Highest CP of a Pokemon: 1024
- Area found: Toronto, Canada
- CPs of  Pokemons found in the mornings 400-700cp
- CPs of Pokemons found at night ranges from 12-300cp

Comment: I really don't think so, but the game's data is still being collected and analyzed. We may find out yet the nature of certain environments/times of day/weather patterns.

Comment: I think if might be true that certain times affect which Pokemon spawn though. Like, "ghost Pokemon only appear after dusk."

Comment: @Ekmod ghosts can spawn during the day as well. I caught a Gastly around 11:30. As for the question it is more likely you find more weak Pokémon if you don't move for a while (like being at home). This has been discussed quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is seems highly unlikely. I have caught low CP in the morning and low CP at night (low as in 15 - 400). I am level 15.

So **no**, the time of day has nothing to do the CP.

Comment: there is a double negative in here ;)

Comment: @Phil where? xD

Comment: "at no time nothing". -> at anytime anything ^^
(or is this just a german understanding of this clauses?)
I would write "It would have no time anything to do with the CP"

Comment: @Phil I just put a comma there, think that was the problem.

Comment: Ah, that a complete different sentence now. Great :D

Answer (score 1):

Kiwi's answer goes off a single player's experience.

[**Data from 2 million Pokemon spawns**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vkcmc08urz_YGuXs7eydFh-PWiFRNxoGWJWv7JE7SnU/pubhtml) confirms this, time of day does **not** relate to Pokemon spawns.

Source: [SilphRoad](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4x4qdd/time_of_day_data_do_certain_pokemon_spawn_more_at/)